# Conditions depending on the value of an array

Tags: c#

Let's suppose i have a dynamic array like this:

```
string[] documentsContentTypes = {".pdf",".docx",".xls"};
```

And now i want to use it to add conditions to an if statement.

In the end, the if will be something like this:

```
if(Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName).ToLower() != ".pdf" && Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName).ToLower() != ".docx" && Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName).ToLower() != ".xls")
return false;
```

I want to make sure that if the extension it's neither of these the function will return false.

how can i achive this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean you want to see if the extension is in the list of content types?

```
var extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName).ToLower();

if(documentsContentTypes.Contains(extension))
{
  // yay!
}
```

To simply return true if the extension is there or false if not:

```
var extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName).ToLower();

return documentsContentTypes.Contains(extension); // true if exists, false otherwise
```

Comment: Hi, i want to make sure that if the documents extensions is neither of those the function will return false.

Comment: Then just return the result of the expression. Updating my answer.

Comment: Yes, using .Contains method does what i want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit way to do it below.  But @DigiFriend's way is more readable IMO.

```
bool doIt = true;
foreach (string type in documentsContentTypes)
{
    if (Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName).ToLower() == type)
    {
        doIt = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (doIt)
{
    // do something interesting
}
```